# Firefox does not apply style to content loaded through Ajax (AngulaJS used)

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, ajax, firefox

I'm working on app (MVC4 + AngularJS). I have very weird issue. 
In Firefox (currently version 42) content loaded though Ajax call not always picks up css style (loaded before).
On the pictures attached you can see that the value text (marked on red) should have     `font-weight: normal` (Firefox Firebug shows normal font - also in computed tab); however the displayed text looks bold. 
I excluded custom font reason (Arial shows the same issue).

I also thought that might be AngularJS issue. Some (required) labels are bold (used conditional `ng-class`), but even if I have removed that `ng-class`, still all text, labels and values were bold.

For me it looks like Firefox does not apply that body style to elements loaded using Ajax call.

Screenshots below:

[image: Live view]
[image: normal font]
[image: bold font]

Comment: I found that if I remove ng-if="field && field.length > 0" from the container div the css issue is gone. So basically FIrefox shows wrong styling on JS-recreated DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Firefox to just released newest version (from 42 to 43), all issues are gone.

Comment: Probably related to the [bug](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-US/docs/2015/css-cascading-may-go-wrong-when-style-is-dynamically-updated/) introduced in Fx 41 (though according to Target Milestone field of the bug, it’s fixed in Fx 44, not 43).